# Error importing specific function in Git Bash on shell login

Tags: bash, shell, unix, git-bash

I'm getting this unusual and annoying error as soon as I login into a bash shell:

```
sh: PATHRE: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: PATHRE: line 4: ` echo c:\Users\Chris Ross\bin;.;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\local\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\mingw\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\bin;c:\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16;c:\Python27\;c:\Python27\Scripts;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\WINDOWS\system32;c:\WINDOWS;c:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;c:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;c:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\;c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Shoes;c:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\xampp\apache\bin;c:\xampp\php;c:\xampp\mysql\bin\;c:\Program Files\nodejs\;c:\Users\Chris Ross\AppData\Roaming\npm;c:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\;c:\utils\ffmpeg\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\;c:\utils;c:\Python27\;c:\Python27\Scripts;c:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16;c:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin;c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;c:\utils\wget-1.11.4-1-bin\bin;c:\utils\iview441_x64;c:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Editor\;c:\Program Files\processing-2.2.1;c:\Program Files\Audacity;c:\utils\Calibre Portable\Calibre;c:\Users\Chris Ross\dotfiles\bin | tr ':' '\n' | while read x; do'
sh: error importing function definition for `PATHRE'

Chris Ross@MACHINE ~
```

This only affects the following function, although the function itself works as expected with no errors:

```
pathre ()
{
    local idx=0;
    local regex='.*';
    [[ ! -z "${1}" ]] && regex="${1}";
    echo "${PATH}" | tr ':' '\n' | while read -r x; do
        (( idx+=1 ));
        echo "${idx} ${x}";
    done | grep -i "${regex}"
}
```

The error occurs whether located in a file that is sourced by `~/.bashrc` or placed in `~/.bashrc`.

The function simply replaces the path separator into newlines to iterate over, and then grep for a substring. It looks like this:

```
$ pathre
1 /c/Users/Chris Ross/bin
2 .
3 /usr/local/bin
[etc...]
```

And with args:

```
$ pathre dot
51 /c/Users/Chris Ross/dotfiles/bin
67 /c/Users/Chris Ross/dotfiles/bin
```

I'm using Git Bash within Console2 on a Windows 10 machine, which I've installed using the RailsInstaller package.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.20(4)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's the exact code that is causing the problem? Because it doesn't look like it.

For starters the error says `PATHRE` and your code uses `pathre`.

Secondly the code in the error indicates that the path is expanded on the command being run (and, in fact, is most likely *actually* the command being run) and that the value of the path is the problem.

As such I expect your code actually looks more like this:

```
PATHRE ()
{
    local idx=0;
    local regex='.*';
    [[ ! -z "${1}" ]] && regex="${1}";
    ${PATH} | tr ':' '\n' | while read -r x; do
        (( idx+=1 ));
        echo "${idx} ${x}";
    done | grep -i "${regex}"
}
```

If that's the case then you can likely fix the problem by *actually* using the code in your snippet and/or finding the `PATHRE` code and deleting it (since it is probably in there somewhere and you just aren't seeing it.

That said this happens to be a fairly poorly written function.

This `awk`-using function is much better.

```
pathre() {
    awk -v RS=: -v re="$1" '!re || $0 ~ re {print NR,$0}' <<<"$PATH"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite (I don't know awk at all).

Comment: The error message actually doesn't seem to change even when I change the function definition, so I guess I have to look harder to see if you are correct about there being another function sourced/written somewhere.